# Is ADS-C used in practice?

Tags: ads-b, ads-c

Both the FAA and the EASA have decided against using ADS-C in the development of NextGen and SESAR, because of cost, scalability and ease of use. But has ADS-C actually been implemented and used in practice anywhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ADS-C is used in oceanic environments, for example over the Atlantic and the Pacific.

FL350 to FL390 on the North Atlantic Track System is restricted to ADS-C equipped aircraft. Non ADS-C aircraft have to fly either below or above those levels (crossing through those levels is permitted)

The text below is a part of today's Norht Atantic Track message issued by Shanwick Center (EGGX):

> 222021 EGGXZOZX
>
> (NAT-2/2 TRACKS FLS 310/390 INCLUSIVE
>
> MAR 23/1130Z TO MAR 23/1900Z
>
> PART TWO OF TWO PARTS-
>
> E MALOT 53/20 53/30 53/40 53/50 RIKAL
>
> EAST LVLS NIL
>
> WEST LVLS 310 320 330 340 350 360 370 380 390
>
> EUR RTS WEST NIL
>
> NAR NIL-
>
> F LIMRI 52/20 52/30 52/40 52/50 TUDEP
>
> EAST LVLS NIL
>
> WEST LVLS 310 320 330 340 350 360 370 380 390
>
> EUR RTS WEST NIL
>
> NAR NIL-
>
> REMARKS.
>
> 1. TMI IS 082 AND OPERATORS ARE REMINDED TO INCLUDE THE
>
> TMI NUMBER AS PART OF THE OCEANIC CLEARANCE READ BACK.
>
> **2. ADS-C AND CPDLC MANDATED OTS ARE AS FOLLOWS**
>
> **TRACK A 350 360 370 380 390**
>
> **TRACK B 350 360 370 380 390**
>
> **TRACK C 350 360 370 380 390**
>
> **TRACK D 350 360 370 380 390**
>
> **TRACK E 350 360 370 380 390**
>
> **TRACK F 350 360 370 380 390**
>
> **END OF ADS-C AND CPDLC MANDATED OTS**