# Does ATC react to pilot position reports?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications, phraseology, oceanic

Following previous questions on position reporting:

- [When do pilots have to submit position reports?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48019)
- [What are pilot position reports?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1553)

Does Air Traffic Control somehow react to pilots submitting position reports, are they acknowledged or even repeated by ATC?

What is the exact phraseology of such an acknowledgement / confirmation (voice, CPDLC, and ADS-C)?

**Edit & Update: The background of this question is commercial oceanic operations. As pointed out in the answers, there are multiple different position reports. This question mainly focuses on oceanic position reports via voice & CPDLC.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the linked and your previous questions I think you mean **oceanic** position reports.

Here's what ICAO Annex 10 Vol II says:

> 5.2.1.9.2.3.1 **PANS.—** *An aeronautical station should acknowledge position reports and other flight progress reports by **reading back the report** and terminating the read back by its call sign, except that the read back procedure may be suspended temporarily whenever it will alleviate congestion on the communication channel.*

An "aeronautical station" will typically have the *radio* [suffix](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/48237/14897), e.g. Santa Maria Radio (LPPO) over the Atlantic.

##### Examples

You can listen to such exchange with Gander Radio over the Atlantic on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oF-Jlo0253A), also:

A [South African AIC](http://www.caa.co.za/IR%20and%20GR%20additional%20study%20references/General%20Radiotelephony%20Operators/AIC%2041.3.pdf) (41.3) on Radiotelephony Procedures provides an oceanic position report example for the quoted Annex 10 paragraph:

> 16.5 [same exact text as above quoted **5.2.1.9.2.3.1**]
>
> *NOTE: the following example illustrates the application of this procedure*
>
> *(Network station acknowledging receipt of position report)*
>
> *Aircraft:
>
> JOHANNESBURG OCEANIC SPRINGBOK SIX ZERO WUN – WUN AIT AIT SIX WUN*
>
> *Station:
>
> SPRINGBOK SIX ZERO WUN – JOHANNESBURG OCEANIC – GO AHEAD*
>
> *Aircraft:
>
> SPRINGBOK SIX ZERO WUN – OVERHEAD UBVER AT WUN SIX – FLIGHT LEVEL WUN AIT
> ZERO – ESTIMATING EXAKO AT WUN TOO TREE AIT*
>
> *Station **(acknowledging):**
>
> SPRINGBOK SIX ZERO WUN – OCEANIC **COPIES** UBVER AT WUN SIX – FLIGHT LEVEL WUN
> AIT ZERO – REPORT AT EXAKO NEXT*
>
> *Aircraft **(denoting correctness of readback):**
>
> REPORT AT EXAKO NEXT SPRINGBOK SIX ZERO WUN*

##### SATCOM and data link

- SATCOM – Acknowledgement / readback (ICAO [Satellite Voice Guidance Material](https://www.icao.int/APAC/Documents/edocs/cns/SATVOICE_SVGM_v1.pdf) § 4.2.2.2)
- ADS-C – No, as long as the system is logged on
- CPDLC – No (ICAO [Global Operational Data Link Document](https://www.icao.int/APAC/Documents/edocs/GOLD_2Edition.pdf) 2nd Edition p. A-37).

Comment: Thank you, @ymb1, this is what I was hoping for. Indeed, I am looking into oceanic operations. I have added more precision to the original question.

Answer (score 8):

I controlled non-radar airspace for about 2.5 years.

On your end, we’ll probably just say “roger.” We may add instructions to report a future point, or a control instruction.

On our end, we would be using that information for any required separation. For example, we may update a flight strip with your groundspeed, recalculate how we anticipate bring traffic across that same point, or change how we are protecting airspace or altitudes according to where you are. It varies depending on the environment and traffic, but the general concept is ATC is protecting the entire block from where we last knew you were - your previous position report or where you were last in radar contact - and your next reporting point. Your position report allows us to modify that protected area.

But little to none of that information will be relayed to the pilot, unless it is operationally necessary. Even then, it will probably just be in the form of a control instruction.

Answer (score 2):

*Note this answer is from a GA point of view*

---

When you give a position report as a GA pilot in uncontrolled airspace, your transmission *is* acknowledged by ATC, often repeating back to you your *actual* position in the case of a Radar controller.

For example, a typical R/T conversation near where I fly may be as follows - this is typical of my first contact with an area Radar controller having changed onto frequency from my departure airport:

> G-CD: Farnborough Radar North, Golf Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta, Request Traffic Service
>   FR: Golf Charlie Delta, Pass your message
>   G-CD: Golf Charlie Delta PA28 2 POB VFR, Routing Elstree to Turweston, 2200 feet 1016 London QNH. Currently abeam Bovingdon heading 270
>   FR: Golf Charlie Delta Sqwark 5020 QNH 1017 Radar contact **2 Miles East of Chesham**, Traffic Service
>   G-CD: Sqwark 5020 1017 QNH

Note the emphasised section. I had given an approximate position to the controller to allow them to identify me. They have used that information along with my transponder code to exactly identify me on their screen, and read back to me my exact location.